# Как в нескольких блоках текста сделать замены?

Tags: java, строки, замена

Допустим:

> Какой-то текjст, какой-то текст,  **{ в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу   на кирjиллицу, }** какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какjой-то текст,  какой-то теjкст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  каjкой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст, **{ в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, }**  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  **{ в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, }** какjой-то текст,  какой-то тjекст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то теjкст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,j  какоjй-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  каjкой-то текст,  кjакой-то текст,  какой-то теjкст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,  какой-то текст,

Вот, как-то так. Грубо говоря, нужно зайти в блок, ограниченный операторскими скобками(причём, за скобками может быть любой символ, включая "пробел" и "абзац или новая строка, не знаю"). Опять же, скобки это условно. Может быть другой тэг. И заменить нужные символы согласно условию.

Т.е. - нужно повыдергивать все блоки между скобками(читай "тэгами") сделать в них replaceAll и вставить обратно. Как будто так и было!

У меня уже все мысли закончились. Вот этот бы код как-то усовершенствовать:

```
String start = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("{"));
String subString = s.substring(s.indexOf("{"), s.indexOf("}"));
String end = s.substring(s.indexOf("}"));
```

Не могу его в цикл задействовать. Короче, нужна помощь! **Особенно рассмотрю варианты с многопоточностью.**

Comment: С многопоточкой это я наверное перегнул)))

Comment: Согласно какому условию нужно заменить символы внутри скобок?

Comment: @iramm да, любое условие. Например, заменить все "j" на "*" . При этом "j", которые за пределами скобок не должны измениться.

Comment: ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603681/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**: *Исправил, согласно замечанию @ArtemKonovalov*

```
String check = "Какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, } " +
            "какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, " +
            "какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, " +
            "какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, } " +
            "какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, } " +
            "какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, " +
            "какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, " +
            "какой-то текст, какой-то текст";

    String replaceRegex = "[A-Za-z]";
    String tagRegex = "\\{.*?"+replaceRegex+".*?}";


    //Определяем мапу с соответствием символов.

    Map<String,String> replaceConst = new HashMap<>();
    replaceConst.put("a","А");
    replaceConst.put("b","Б");
    //...
    replaceConst.put("j","Ъ");

    Matcher tagMatcher = Pattern.compile(tagRegex).matcher(check);

    while (tagMatcher.find()){
        String replaceString = tagMatcher.group();
        Matcher replaceMatcher = Pattern.compile(replaceRegex).matcher(replaceString);
        while (replaceMatcher.find()){
            replaceString = replaceString.replace(replaceMatcher.group(),replaceConst.get(replaceMatcher.group()));
        }

        check = check.replace(tagMatcher.group(),replaceString);
    }
```

Output:

> Какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомЪ блоке нужно заменить
>   лЪатиницу на кирЪиллицу, } какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то
>   текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст,
>   какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст,
>   какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомЪ блоке нужно
>   заменить лЪатиницу на кирЪиллицу, } какой-то текст, какой-то текст,
>   какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомЪ блоке нужно заменить
>   лЪатиницу на кирЪиллицу, } какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то
>   текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст,
>   какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст,
>   какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст,
>   какой-то текст

Comment: В этом решении разве учитываются границы замены? насколько я понял, автор вопроса хотел произвести замену только в тексте между символами "{" и "}"

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov спасибо за замечание. Исправил. Правда теперь выглядит не очень красиво, но работает.

Answer (score 2):

У меня получилось несколько решений.

Если требуется заменить несколько символов, в заданном блоке то следующий метод это делает:

```
private static String replaceAll(String text,
                                 Map<Character, Character> symbols,
                                 String leftBorder,
                                 String rightBorder) {

    String patternTemplate = Pattern.quote(leftBorder) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(rightBorder);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternTemplate);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String replaceText = matcher.group();
        for (Entry<Character, Character> entry : symbols.entrySet())
            replaceText = replaceText.replace(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

        text = text.replace(matcher.group(), replaceText);
    }

    return text;
}
```

Вызывается следующим образом:

```
Map<Character, Character> symbols = new HashMap<>();
symbols.put('j', 'Ъ');
symbols.put('к', 'K');
symbols.put('з', 'З');

String result = replaceAll(text, symbols, "{", "}");
```

Если же, необходимо заменить только строку, то можно воспользоваться вот этим методом:

```
private static String replaceAll(String text,
                                 String replaceText,
                                 String substitutionText,
                                 String leftBorderText,
                                 String rightBorderText) {

    String patternTemplate =
            "(?<=" + Pattern.quote(leftBorderText) + ")" +
                    "(.*?)[" + replaceText + "](.*?)" +
                    "(?=" + Pattern.quote(rightBorderText) + ")";

    String substitutionTemplate = "$1" + substitutionText + "$2";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternTemplate);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String result = matcher.replaceAll(substitutionTemplate);
        return replaceAll(result, replaceText, substitutionText, leftBorderText, rightBorderText);
    } else
        return text;
}
```

Вызывать так:

```
String replaceText = "j";
String substitution = "Ъ";

String result = replaceAll(text, replaceText, substitution, "{", "}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю можно использовать регулярку

```
String value = "Какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, } какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, } какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, { в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, } какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст, какой-то текст";
String result = value.replaceAll("\{.*?\}","какой-то текст 2");
```

Результат поиска по regex
[image: Результат поиска регулярки]

Comment: Не годится. Мне нужен такой ответ: было - { в этомj блоке нужно заменить лjатиницу на кирjиллицу, }, стало - { в этомЪ блоке нужно заменить лЪатиницу на кирЪиллицу, }. Содержимое блоков может быть разное!

Comment: @JürgenvonMarkoff не понял вопрос изначально
тоисть надо заменить **J** на **А** ?

Comment: @JürgenvonMarkoff окей, с помощью даной регулярки можете просто искаль блоки, потом сделать регулярку которая будет проверяться если данные которые нужно изменить (или через Java `String.contains()`) и менять

Comment: Аналогично работе тегов в html. Нужно в тексте который находится внутри скобок поменять **J** на **А** допустим. И так по всему основному тексту.

Comment: @JürgenvonMarkoff регулярка не очень, но все же
`<b>.*j.*</b>` - ищете в html теге **j** если есть replaceAll to **a**

Comment: не-а..! не помогло.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49932/discussion-between-bazjaz-and-jurgen-von-markoff).